# Non-win programmes on Win 10 via Ubuntu

Tags: bash, windows-10

The question is whether I can install a non-win program like gscan2pdf via bash terminal in Windows 10 and whether it will work? Since there is a possibility to install Ubuntu into Win 10 as a feature and use a Linux terminal, I wonder what kind of program could be installed? Is that like the virtualization of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. WSL2 is basically a Linux virtual machine built into Windows. You can install most Linux software in WSL2.

Comment: But now GUI dependent software without and extraordinary amount of effort since WSL/WSL2 has not been designed for that.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've installed an X server and PulseAudio on Windows and at this point it all Just Works(tm), so I sometimes forget how much effort it took back when I set it up. True, GUI software is a different ballpark altogether.